# my view action not showing any data. CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, view, routes, param

This my link in newsses/index.ctp

```
$this->Html->link(__("Read more >>", TRUE), array('action'=>'view', $newss['Newsse']['title']));
```

and this my view code in newsses_controller.php:

```
function view($title = NULL){
    $this->set('title_for_layout', __('News & Event', true));

    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid News.', true), 'default', array('class' => 'error')); 
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    $this->set('newsse', $this->Newsse->read(NULL,$title));
    $this->set('newsses', $this->Newsse->find('all'));
}
```

but it does't showing anything,
i want to make route like:
"newsses/view/2" to "newsses/view/title_of_news"

please help me....

Comment: Just a note, you can name your model News and cake will understand that the controller will also be News

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the `Model::read()` method method which takes as the second argument the `id` of the row in your Model's table that you want to access. It's better to use find in this case. You don't need to build a new method in your model or your controller, you can just edit the current `view` method.

```
# in newsses_controller.php:
 function view($title = null) {
     $this->set('title_for_layout', __('News & Event', true));

     if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid News.', true), 'default', array('class' => 'error')); 
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }

    $this->set('newsse', $this->Newsse->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Newsse.title' => $title)
    ));
    $this->set('newsses', $this->Newsse->find('all'));
}
```

Or, you can make a more hybrid form in which viewing by id is still possible when a numerical title is given (this assumes you never have news items which have a title consisting of only numeric characters, e.g. '12345').

```
# in newsses_controller.php:
 function view($title = null) {
     $this->set('title_for_layout', __('News & Event', true));

     if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid News.', true), 'default', array('class' => 'error')); 
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    } else if (is_numeric($title)) {
        $this->set('newsse', $this->Newsse->read(NULL, $title));
    } else {
        $this->set('newsse', $this->Newsse->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array('Newsse.title' => $title)
        ));
    }

    $this->set('newsses', $this->Newsse->find('all'));
}
```

Finally, you can also replace the `find` method in my example with a (shorter) custom `findBy` method (see the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1026/findBy) for more info about this).

```
$this->Newsse->findByTitle($title);
```

Comment: and how about route, url param, i want make title as a param and i want that title lowercase and have underscore, and how the view function in controller read that param...?.

Comment: With default routing set up, /newsses/view/this_is_a_title will automatically work the way you want.

Comment: And your requirements for the title should be used when you create the title of your item (in the `add()` method for instance). You can easily create a nice title with `Inflector::slug()`.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to create a new method in your model Which will display result by news title. At this time your using $this->Newsse->read(NULL,$title)). You are using $title in read method while this read method search against news id in model. So you just need to create a new method in model class like readByTitle($title){ write query here to fetch news by title }. And use this method in your controller. $this->Newsse->readByTitle(NULL,$title))